# PhoneGap 0.9.6 (Blackberry) + Sencha Touch 1.1.0: deviceready does not fire

Tags: blackberry, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm trying to build an app that uses PhoneGap 0.9.6 and Sencha Touch 1.1.0 for Blackberry. (The app is already running fine on iOS and Android).

Unfortunately the crucial deviceready event does not fire anymore once I include the Sencha Touch files. This is how I tested:

1. Build the PhoneGap example app as described on http://www.phonegap.com/start#blackberry using the BlackBerry WebWorks Packager 2.0.0
2. Edit index.html so it's shorter and add alerts in init() and deviceInfo() and run the example on the Blackberry emulator 6.0.0.227. (Could not figure out how to add a code block with HTML so please go to http://pastebin.com/rUU1bDbL to see the modified code.) Everything is still working.
3. Include the css and js of Sencha Touch 1.1.0: http://pastebin.com/Y4Vydby1 After that change the function deviceInfo does not get called anymore.

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/2e378b2aad23ca50) a similar problem with jQuery Mobile can be solved by changing the order of the includes but every combination I tried had the same problem.

Is this a general problem? Is someone successfully using PhoneGap 0.9.6 and Sencha Touch 1.1.0 on Blackberry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporary solution:  revert to PhoneGap 0.9.5.1

This seems to be a problem encountered by most people trying to work with Phonegap/Sencha on Blackberry recently.

We found that the basic PhoneGap Sample demo would break as soon as we included the sencha.js library, even though we were not even using it.  I.e., the Sample demo runs fine on Blackberry, but if you then include sencha.js it no longer operates properly.

Someone reported that they resolved the problem by reverting to 0.9.5.1 version of PhoneGap.  That worked for us, but 1.0.0 does not.

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/3ed0192e44a49ad1/6be7980f9164c455?lnk=gst&q=blackberry+sencha#6be7980f9164c455

We would love to see this fixed so that we can be running the latest version of PhoneGap.

The issue has popped on on various forums lately, but doesn't appear to have Phonegap's attention yet.

e.g., https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-blackberry-webworks/issues/44#issue_comment_form    ("No one is assigned")

This seems like a major problem because it makes it impossible for anyone to do anything on a new Blackberry that uses PhoneGap/Sencha. I know there have been a lot of other things fixed between 0.9.5.1 and 1.0.0 so I am worried about fielding an app using the older version.

Keith Levi