# Integrate sencha touch 2 into phonegap, cannot get 'deviceready' event to fire up

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events, sencha-touch-2

This seems to be another issue than [PhoneGap 0.9.6 (Blackberry) + Sencha Touch 1.1.0: deviceready does not fire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611417/phonegap-0-9-6-blackberry-sencha-touch-1-1-0-deviceready-does-not-fire) it's related to iOS.

So, I can't get that event to fire up; using latest cordova (phonegap) 1.6.1.

Has anyone been successfully integrating these ST2 and PhoneGap?

Here's my app.json :

```
"js": [
    {   
        "path": "resources/js/cordova-1.6.1.js",
        "update": "delta"
    },
    {
        "path": "sdk/sencha-touch.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "update": "delta"
    },
],
```

My app.js:

```
launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();
    var mainPanel = Ext.Viewport.add({
        xclass: 'Sencha.view.Main'
    });

    // load phonegap stuff
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        mainPanel.fireEvent("deviceready");
    } , true);
},
```

My Main.js controller :

```
Ext.define('Sencha.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    
config: {
    refs: {
        mainPanel: 'mainpanel',
    },
    control: {
        mainpanel: {
            deviceready: 'onDeviceReady'
        },
    },
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
    Ext.Msg.alert('Connection type', states[networkState], Ext.emptyFn);
    navigator.notification.beep(2);
},
```

Comment: I have successfully integrated older versions (PG 1.2, ST 1.1).  Did your code work in prior PhoneGap versions or is this a new issue?  What happens if you test the PhoneGap event listener separately (just show an alert) from the Sencha Touch event (fire the event from elsewhere)?

Comment: Hi, not sure to understand; how can I fire up the listener separately; can you give an example ? My work env. is ST2 PG 1.7.0

Comment: I'm wondering if you can narrow down the scope of the issue.  Does an alert show if you do:  `document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () { alert('deviceready'); } , true);`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Adding your line in index.html works fine but not anywhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sencha Touch 2 will listen to that event and call your onReady/launch methods - therefore if you try listening to them in the launch method, it has already been fired.

Just put your logic inside the launch method in your application.